# Changing the Virtualmin, Webmin and Usermin default ports

Tags: port, ubuntu-12.04

I am attempting to change the default ports for Virtualmin, Webmin and Usermin on an Ubuntu 12.04 server.

After doing the below, I am only able to access the Usermin console.

1. Opened port 9988 on the firewall.
2. Changed the Usermin port to 9988.
3. Webmin -> Webmin -> Usermin Configuration -> Ports and Addresses.
4. Browse to myserver.com:9988

Why am I not able to access the Webmin and Virtualmin console after these changes?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It is not about a specific service providers management interface. It is about Webmin in general which is `tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating these` http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I was not realizing that Webmin/Virtualmin uses port 10000 by default and Usermin uses port 20000 by default.

You must do the following to change the default ports for both Webmin/Virtualmin and Usermin:

1. Opened port 9988 on the firewall.
2. Changed the **Webmin** port to 9988.
3. Webmin -> Webmin -> **Webmin Configuration** -> Ports and Addresses.
4. Browse to myserver.com:9988
5. Opened port 19988 on the firewall.
6. Changed the **Usermin** port to 19988.
7. Webmin -> Webmin -> **Usermin Configuration** -> Ports and
   Addresses.
8. Browse to myserver.com:9988

I could not find this documented anywhere and every example only talked about changing the Webmin default port only.

Accidentally clicking on the Usermin configuration is an easy mistake to make. I hope this helps someone in the future.